# Raspberry Pi i2c-tools Install Failing

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I need to install i2c-tools on my Raspberry Pi, but I'm running into a mountain of troubles.

I've tried multiple variations to install, mostly similar to [this one from spkang.co.uk](http://skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/575)

but without any luck.  Upon running sudo apt-install i2c-tools, I get the error message `/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.`

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf is completely empty and there are no references to i2c in neither the alsa-base-blacklist.conf nor the fbdev-blacklist.conf in the same location.

/etc/modules shows just two kernel modules (snd-bcm2835 and i2c-dev)

pi is added to the i2c group

sudo i2cdetect -y 0 and sudo i2cdetect y 1 both produce the same error `Error: Could not open file '/dev/i2c-0' or '/dev/i2c/0': No such file or directory`.  Of course, the /dev/i2c* are not present on the system.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?  I'm using a wheezy 7.8 image that came with a lcd touchscreen.  The results of uname -a are `Linux raspberrypi 3.18.9-v7 #27 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 4 23:57:41 CST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux`.

From /boot/config.txt I've added the following lines:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#device_tree=bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
device_tree_param=i2c1=on
device_tree_param=spi=on
```

The line I commented out was removed because the pi would not boot with this line present.

Thanks in advance for saving me from the insanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same trouble. I add only these lines to the /boot/config.txt

```
dtparam=i2c1=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was some sort of a kernel conflict with the image that was required by the touchscreen build. I returned that touchscreen and upgraded to a 7' HDMI screen and used the NOOB install and it works fine.